# Is it possible to create a schema under Catalogs?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm working on a customized template database and I'd like to organize some functions and views in a schema that is apart from where database users are looking or might consider their domain - basically i want to keep it clean.

Meaning, i'd like alongside pg_catalog and information_schema (under 'Catalogs') as opposed to being listed under 'Schemas' ( if you looking at it via pgAdmin for example ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between “catalogs” and “schemas” is purely an artifact of pgAdmin; PostgreSQL has no such distinction. So you would have to modify the source code of pgAdmin to make that happen.